# Policies of Passing Two(Multi) Dimensional Array to Function in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory

I've already known the policy of passing multi-dimensional array as parameter to function, which is the parameter in the function declaration and definition must include the column size; but the row size is irrelevant and can be omitted.

But I don't know the reason. After doing some research, here is my understanding so far(plz correct me if incorrect!):

While passing an array as an argument to a function, regardless of dimension parameters, array always decays into pointer pointing to its first element. And the element may be another array!
For a 2D array, eg. `int arr[3][4]`, arr is an array of three `int[4]`, so `int[4]` is the element of `arr`. Hence, `void foo(int a[3][4])` will decay to `void foo(int (*a)[4])`, which points to the first `int[4]`!

Now `arr` points to 1st element(say address is 5000) which is the first `int[4]`, and here comes the question: What address should compiler index for `arr+1`? The address of `arr+1` is specified by the COLUMN SIZE, which is:

> 5000 + 4(column size, int/column) * 4(bytes/int) = 5016!

So, what really matters is how to index the array, instead of the size of the array! Hence, dimensions besides the outermost are all necessary !

However, I have a question, how does the compiler know where is the boundary of the array in the memory? For the above example, without the row size 3, how does the compiler know to stop at

> 5000(arr[0][0]) + 16 * (3-1) = 5032(arr[2][0])

instead of accessing 5048 and so on? Or is there some additional bits before each piece of data specifying the total size of the array?

Any explanation or help is appreciated! Thanks a lot:)

Comment: C doesn't have any bounds-checking. And it's impossible to pass arrays to functions (outside of structures), all arrays decays to pointers to their first elements. And once an array have decayed to a pointer, the compiler looses all information about the array size.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, not exactly. The size of an array is bound to its type. The size is lost when the type is lost. It one passes an array by a pointer to an array then there is no decay and the size of an array can be recovered.

Comment: @tstanisl Yes you can pass a pointer to the array and there's no decay, because you're not passing the array but a pointer to it.

Comment: If you wanted the function to know the number of rows you would need to pass the number of rows in an additional parameter, and the function code would need to take that into account. (E.g. `void foo(size_t nrows, int (*a)[4])`.)

Comment: The compiler doesn't know. The programmer knows (or should know).

Answer (score 1):

> must include the column size; but the row size is irrelevant and can
> be omitted.

For the array access, it is fine, but the function will not know if you access the array outside its bounds.

> While passing an array as an argument to a function, regardless of
> dimension parameters, array always decays into pointer pointing to its
> first element. And the element may be another array

An array is only a continuous chunk of memory. Array of arrays is exactly the same. It will decay to the pointer referencing the first element of the array inside the array. Only type will be different and compiler will warn you about it.

> However, I have a question, how does the compiler know where is the
> boundary of the array in the memory? For the above example, without
> the row size 3, how does the compiler know to stop at

Compiler does not know as C does not check the limits of the array indexes. If you access the element outside the array it invokes **U***ndefined* **B***ehavior*

Comment: So the main reason row size doesn't need to be specified is because array decays to the pointer referencing the first element when passed as a parameter, and row size is irrelevant to that pointer?

Comment: @CalvinLin columns are needed to know how to calculate the address of the element of the array. But C does not check bounds